# Find and replace/remove two words from a string using regex c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm trying to read scripts from various .sql files into a string and execute them in SQL server using c#. I want to remove the terms USE, GO etc. I succeeded removing one word at a time but cannot find the pattern to search for two or more words at the same time.

so far,

```
string pattern =  @"\bUSE*\b";
string script = Regex.Replace(script, pattern, "");
```

How to add other search terms to the pattern? i tried msdn docs and previous questions but cannot find what i need. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pipe in your keywords.

```
string pattern =  @"\b(USE|GO|MORE|FEW_MORE|AND_SO_ON)\b";
```

Comment: Seriously, by 7 seconds?? :-) - And yours is neater!

Comment: This works thanks. What if I need to search for something like this [string] ? I tried @"\b(USE|GO|[table1])\b"; but it doesn't work. thanks again

Comment: @kcube you need to escape the square brackets with backslash

Comment: You have to escape the `[` and `]` characters. Like this way: `\[table1\]`

Comment: @"\b(USE|\[Northwind\])\b"; It is still showing [Northwind] in the script :\

Comment: I mean \[Northwind\] and its still showing. Esc.Seq got removed in my previous comment, so posting again!

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Here it should be: `@"\b(USE|\[Northwind\])\b";` Use this character ` around your code to show this as code :-)

Comment: I'm using exactly the same thing `@"\b(USE|\[Northwind\])\b";` and it still shows the term. p.s thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Looks like the `\b` doesn't work with near by adjacent non-word characters!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little rusty, but have you tried

```
string pattern = @"\bUSE*\b|\bGO*\b"
```

??

Comment: This removes only USE :\